# Add header and trailer using awk

Tags: unix, header, awk

Below is my splitting files using awk, but I want to add header and trailer.

How can i do this?

```
awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR==1 {h=$0; next} { gsub(/"/, "", $1); file="Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"; print (a[file]++?"":h ORS) $0 > file}' Test_01012020.CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print them in the BEGIN and END Section accordingly:

```
$ h=$'Fruit\tColor'
$ t=$'Total\tTotal'
$ cat file 
Mango Yellow
Lemon Green
$ awk -v h="$h" -v t="$t" 'BEGIN{FS=" ";OFS="\t";print h}{print $1,$2}END{print t}' file
Fruit   Color
Mango   Yellow
Lemon   Green
Total   Total
```

Alternativelly,
You can avoid the external variables and print header directly inside awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" ";OFS="\t";print "Fruit","Color"}{print $1,$2}END{print "Total","Total"}' file
```

Comment: I could not get this @George Vasiliou :(

Comment: @FARAH Why not? Seems quite simple. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @FARAH See the alternative method with direct printing at BEGIN/END

Comment: my command error when i try to run. do i need to put  $ h=$'Fruit\tColor'
$ t=$'Total\tTotal'
$ cat file  inside my unix?

Comment: @FARAH This is just a test. I created a test file with a couple of lines. You can print directly header / footer with out any $h or $t - see alternative method and change the head / tail texts according to your script. You can see my test here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMX01sV3E0SjIzZFE

Comment: actually I want to make one sentence that able to do splitting with added header and trailer, this is my original splitting files command without header and trailer : **awk -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NR==1 {h=$0; next} { gsub(/"/, "", $1); file="Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"; print (a[file]++?"":h ORS) $0 > file}' Test_01012020.CSV** //How can I insert header and trailer inside the existing command? @George Vasiliou

Comment: @FARAH Post a couple of lines from file Test_01012020.CSV

Comment: I dont understand. Post couple of line? @George Vasiliou

Comment: @FARAH Include some lines of your Test_01012020.CSV file in your queston to be able to understand what you have and what you want. Or you can edit your question and advise what is the input file and what is the desirable output file.

Comment: In my data, I have name,class,age,course,score and etc. But i want to put header for example 01012017 and my trailer i want to put Pass @george vasiliou

Comment: @FARAH You need to edit your question and advise input and expected output. See for example this question that the person who asked has include input file and output file : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384007/linux-awk-remove-strings-by-specific-delimiter

Comment: @FARAH Moreover from your comment it seems that what you really want is to insert a field in the beginning and a field in the end of each row. This is different than "header/trailer". Terms header and trailer refer to one fixed row at beginning of file and on the end of file (full complete row)