# Remove strings by a specific delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have few columns in a file, in which the second column has ":" delimiter and I would like to remove the first, third and fourth strings in the second column and left the second string in that column. But I have the normal delimiter space, so I have no idea.

```
input:

--- 22:16050075:A:G 16050075 A G
--- 22:16050115:G:A 16050115 G A
--- 22:16050213:C:T 16050213 C T
--- 22:16050319:C:T 16050319 C T
--- 22:16050527:C:A 16050527 C A

desired output:

--- 22 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 22 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 22 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 22 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 22 16050527 16050527 C A

Wrong:
cat df.txt | awk -F: '{print $1, $3, $6, $7, $8}'

--- 22 A
--- 22 G
--- 22 C
--- 22 C
--- 22 C
```

but I can not do it right. can awk and sed command can do it?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried the above. it just separated them successfully, but can't choose the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `POSIX` compatible `split()` function on `$2` as

```
awk '{split($2,temp,":"); $2=temp[2];}1' file
--- 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 16050527 16050527 C A
```

Split the column 2 on de-limiter `:`, update the `$2` value to the required element (`temp[2]`) and print the rest of the fields (`{}1` re-constructs all individual fields based on `FS` and prints it).

Recommend this over using multiple de-limiters, as it alters the absolute position of the individual fields, while `split()` makes it easy to retain the position and just extract the required value.

---

For your updated requirement to add a new column, just do

```
awk '{split($2,temp,":"); $2=temp[1] FS temp[2];}1' file
--- 22 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 22 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 22 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 22 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 22 16050527 16050527 C A
```

---

Alternatively if you have `GNU awk`/`gawk` you can use its `gensub()` for a regex (using `POSIX` character class `[[:digit]]`) based extraction as

```
awk '{$2=gensub(/^([[:digit:]]+):([[:digit:]]+).*$/,"\\1 \\2","g",$2);}1' file
--- 22 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 22 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 22 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 22 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 22 16050527 16050527 C A
```

The `gensub(/^([[:digit:]]+):([[:digit:]]+).*$/,"\\1 \\2","g",$2)` part captures only the first two fields de-limited by `:` with the capturing groups `\\1` and `\\2` and printing the rest of the fields as such.

Comment: what if I print                                                                                                 --- 22 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 22 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 22 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 22 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 22 16050527 16050527 C A

Answer (score 4):

You can also try the following as an alternative to @Inian's much better and more portable solution-

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{print $1, $3, $6, $7, $8}' file
```

Where `file` contains your initial input.

Output-

```
--- 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 16050527 16050527 C A
```

**EDIT**

With the change in the input file (additional column number 2), the command above can be changed to give-

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{print $1, $2, $3, $6, $7, $8}' file
```

Output

```
--- 22 16050075 16050075 A G
--- 22 16050115 16050115 G A
--- 22 16050213 16050213 C T
--- 22 16050319 16050319 C T
--- 22 16050527 16050527 C A
```

Comment: You missed column $2, just add it.

Comment: @ClaesWikner, OP changed the input file. I changed my command now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

You could use sed too:

```
sed -r 's/..:([^:]+)[^ ]+/\1/' file
```